# How do I load data from a url to a .gz file into Pig?

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs, amazon-emr, emr, webhdfs

I want to use Amazon's Elastic MapReduce and run a pig script on about 2TB of data. The problem is I necessarily need to use PigStorage, since I need the tagsource option in my program.

I'm not sure, but I think PigStorage loads data only from HDFS. I need it to read data from the URL below or I need to load data onto HDFS directly from a URL:
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/2008/2008-01/

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You need to copy the data to an S3 bucket first. The first few paragraphs of this article deals with the exact same thing: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2013/06/28/using-sap-hana-to-analyze-wikipedia-data-preparing-the-data

Comment: Thanks a ton! Exactly the thing I needed to know!